# Converting byte object into string supports ulmaut characters

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, byte, mainframe

Data is coming from IBM mainframe interface. Need to convert object message into String for further processing.

```
public EventBody processICMessage(final Object incomingMsg) throws Exception
{
String inMsg = "";

if (incomingMsg instanceof String)
{
 inMsg = (String) incomingMsg;
}
else
{
 byte[] incomingMsgArr = (byte[]) incomingMsg;
 inMsg = new String((byte[]) incomingMsg, "UTF-8");             
}
}
```

Firstly the encoding was Cp1047 which was unable to handle umlaut characters. To mention data consists of German umlaut characters like ä, c̈, p̈ etc. In order to support umlaut chars we changed encoding to UTF-8 which causing blank data in 'imMsg' String. So ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException is coming for further substring operation.

Comment: "In order to support umlaut chars we changed encoding to UTF-8 which causing blank data in 'imMsg' String" - it's not clear whether you mean you *just* changed it in this code, or whether you changed it in the code creating the data to start with. You can't just randomly pick an encoding - it has to match the encoding used to generate the code to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet  Cp1047 supports IBM 1047 but does not support german ulmaut characters. On the other hand UTF-8 supports german ulmaut characters but does not support IBM 1047. Need to find a way where byte data would be converted to String as well as correctly display umlaut chars in UI.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "UTF-8 does not support IBM 1047" - which characters that can be encoded by IBM 1047 cannot be encoded by UTF-8? They may be encoded differently, but that's not the same thing. It's still unclear whether or not you are able to change the IBM code to use UTF-8. You can't just change the reading code.

Comment: Just to add to Jon Skeet's points, if you have EBCDIC data inbound with umlaut characters, the encoding may very well not be 1047, but one of the European equivalents (1141, for instance). One way to tell is to look at the actual hex values of the characters in question and compare them with the codepage maps you'll find in the IBM documentation. Once you know for certain what the incoming encoding is, you  should be able to convert it to UTF-8 without issue, since UTF-8 is generally a superset of all the common EBCDIC encodings.

Comment: Of course, if you control the software on the mainframe side, it would make sense to have the conversion to UTF-8 on that side before the data is transmitted. Depending on the application, IBM provides a usable iconv() function that can be called to translate from one encoding to another, and that way your receiving software doesn't need to jump through hoops to figure out what it's been given. It would not be uncommon for a given mainframe to have users with many different codepages, so trying to figure this out off the mainframe is very difficult.